# Cant add class to Visual Studio UML Architecture Model

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, architecture, modeling

I cant add a class to a Visual Studio UML Architecture Model.

When I drag/drop a class from the Solution Explorer onto the UML model the mouse cursor changes to a "cant drop" icon.

Also in Architecture Explorer its not showing any types or namespaces:

[image]

The class definitely has a namespace and types, its a been generated from a wsdl file. I've tried other classes like the ColourObject.cs (full of types) and encounter the same problem.

[image]

Video's I've seen show people just dragging classes onto the model and abra-cad-abra.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I see my mistake, I could built the project fine.

Though when I added vanilla class to the UML model (from the UMLModel Explorer) and generated, then a Lib Project was created. I added my wsdl Proxy Class file to the Lib Project and tried to built and it failed.

It failed due to some missing references like System.Web and System.Web.Services after adding them the project built fine and then Architecture Explorer showed me all the Types and I was able drag/drop them onto the Model.